# Visual Studio: Deleting (dead) references to nonexistent variables

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I believe this might be a common problem, although I couldn't find any solution to this.

I have 2 projects:
First one is a set of user controls;
Second is a fairly big table (about 100 controls) using those controls.

At some point I tried to implement a feature into user controls that added extra properties and designer automatically assigned values to them in the second project.
Later on I found a more efficient way to implement the feature so I removed all traces of it from my user controls.

Now I have Project2, which is filled with about 100 user control each of which assigns a value to 1-2 no longer existing properties.

To summarize: I've got a project with a lot of dead references that gives me the following error:

> 'MyObject' does not contain a definition for 'OldProperty' and no
>   extension method 'OldProperty' accepting a first argument of type
>   '[value]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

So I would like to ask, Does visual studio have a way to quickly delete the lines containing dead references, or is the only way manual deletion?

Comment: I would recommend a tool like Resharper.  https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_refactoring.html?gclid=Cj0KEQiAypGjBRCPme6jmqu3gZsBEiQA8NAiIHuNoFihZUdmerE9IvOqNfkq5_NfXhShj2KYUNsR5PoaAq068P8HAQ

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all unused members or objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1622774/how-to-find-all-unused-members-or-objects)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install Resharper as a trial.  Delete all your unused references.  If you like the software (and I believe you will), buy yourself a license.  It's my number #1 choice for a dev tool addon and I miss it severely when I don't have it.

Comment: I will give it a try in a second

Comment: I have tried it, although the tool is nice, i didn't find a way to remove multiple assignments to nonexistent variables.